# How do I manipulate curves of animated textures?? (not showing in graph editor)

Tags: animation

Animated the mapping coordinates of a texture (pressed i with cursor over attributes) - but can't see these keys in timeline/dopesheet/graph editor.

I need to adjust the interpolation of these keys and also ad some modifiers to these curves.

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured the issue out.
Normally if I select an object, it's animated properties show up in the animation editors (graph/dope/timeline)... but it seems that to access animated attributes of an object's shader nodetree, both the object AND it's animated shader node has to be selected.

I selected the object in a 3d viewport, and also clicked on the animated shader node in the shader editor.... and the animated channels where available for editing in the graph/dope sheet/timline.